# Create-react-app: how to define context-path of development server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

I'm using Create-react-app with `npm start` command to serve my application in the development server. By default the application is served from https://localhost:3000/. However my application uses cookies which requires specific context path. How do I serve the application from https://localhost:3000/app/ instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options here.

**Production Mode**

Set the environment variable `PUBLIC_PATH` to `/app/`

or

As mentioned in the other answer, use `homepage` field in package.json

**Development Mode**

The config is more of hardcoded into the app. You need to `eject` the app first to make any edits.

**Step 1**

`npm run eject`

**Step 2**

In `config/webpack.config.js`,  Find the below section (Somewhere around line 67 - 68)

```
const publicPath = isEnvProduction
    ? paths.servedPath
    : isEnvDevelopment && '/';
```

and change to

```
 const publicPath = isEnvProduction
        ? paths.servedPath
        : isEnvDevelopment && '/app/';
```

**Step 3**

In `config/webpackDevServer.config.js`, find the below section (Somewhere around line 60 - 65)

```
 // It is important to tell WebpackDevServer to use the same "root" path
 // as we specified in the config. In development, we always serve from /.
 publicPath: '/',
```

And change to

```
publicPath: '/app',
```

**Step 4**

```
npm start
```

Comment: The environment variable pointed in the answer does not work. I found the `PUBLIC_URL` in the tool docs and it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the path by adding: `"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath"` to your package.json file according to the documentation found here:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved this problem with:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/app" />
<Link to="/test" />
```

With this solution, that `Link` path is `/app/test`.

Another example:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/app">
    <Routes>
        <Route element={<Home />} path="/" exact />
        <Route element={<Test />} path="/test" />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```